# How to remove a character from windows character map using C#

Tags: c#

I using a character map tool developed in C# to imitating windows character map. I need to disable some characters loading in to my character map. How to restrict characters loading to the map?

```
FontFamily font = fonts.SelectedItem as FontFamily;
foreach (Typeface typeface in font.GetTypefaces())
{
    typeface.TryGetGlyphTypeface(out glyph);
    if (glyph != null)
    {
        characterMap = glyph.CharacterToGlyphMap;
    }

    int index = characterMap.Keys.ElementAt(i);
    char c = Convert.ToChar(index);
    view.charcter.Text = c.ToString();
```

Comment: You'll need to create a new directory from the *characterMap*.  Iterate the keys and omit the ones you don't like.